# Datepicker Example at jqueryui.com doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Try this:

Navigate to:  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Cut/Paste the code in "view source" to your own new HTML page and see if it actually works.

Tried this in Chrome and Firefox.

One thing I noticed is that they don't wrap the function in '$(document).ready(function ()'

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be clear about what isn't working for you? JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonAller/BzM6b/1/

Comment: Even on their own example page, the calendar will popup when you place your cursor in the text area for the data.

In their example code, it does not do this.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting from Datepicker?

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided works perfect.  (with the exact same Javascript no less)

Comment: What behavior am i expecting?  I'm expecting it to do the same as their exmaple on that page - the same as the jsfilldle you provided code does.

Comment: When you view the JavaScript console in your browser are you seeing any errors when you load or refresh the page you are trying to use Datepicker on?

Comment: _“One thing I noticed is that they don't wrap the function in '$(document).ready(function ()'”_ – because `$(function()` is the current way to do that, it has the same effect.

Comment: Are you maybe calling your test page not via `http://…`, but by directly opening the file in your browser, so that it gets openend via `file://` instead …? Then of course the protocol-relative referencing of the external resources with `//` at the beginning can not work, you would have to replace `//` with `http://` explicitly … (`/resources/demos/style.css` can be neglected, that only defines a font-family and -size.)

Comment: Turned out to be the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

As saied Jason Aller in the comment :

> The reason they are using // at the beginning rather than http:// is
>   so that it will be protocol agnostic and work with https connections.
>   It avoids mixed content security warnings, but breaks when the
>   protocol is file:// –  Jason Aller

So just add `http:` before `//code.jquery.com`

Comment: Tried this direct placement.  Doesn't fix the problem.  Maybe it is the Doc type or something?

Comment: I'd forget `http:` in the example, i do the correction, It's work for me.

Comment: That was it! Adding http: to the changes worked for me.

Comment: The reason they are using `//` at the beginning rather than `http://` is so that it will be protocol agnostic and work with https connections. It avoids mixed content security warnings, but breaks when the protocol is `file://`

Comment: By the way... adding "http:" to their original JQuery version also works.

Comment: @ScottSavage: Yes also. The reason is that my browser removes `http` as in the example of the question. I'll complete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

  var options = $.extend({},
    $.datepicker.regional["ja"], {
      dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      highlightWeek: true
    }
  );

  $("#japaneseCalendar").datepicker(options);
});
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Japanese JQuery UI Datepicker</h3>
<input type="text" id="japaneseCalendar"/>

</body>
</html>
```